# Need program - "editor" that lets you check-mark lines to keep

Tags: text-processing, editors, application

I was wondering if anybody could recommend a program or plug-in (for an editor) to solve the following problem:  I have a file with a large list (one line per item).  I need to manually go through this list and pick out which items (ie. lines) to keep.  Then I would save these lines to a new file.

Usually, I would just fire-up some suitable editor and put an asterisk at the beginning of the lines I want to keep, then use `sed` to select these lines (and remove the asterisk) and redirect it to a file.  But this time there are so many lines it would become cumbersome.

I was therefor wondering if anybody knows of a program/plug-in that would do something along these lines:  A GUI "editor" that add a check-box in the front of each line, and where only the lines that are checked will be subsequently saved to a new file.

Bonus (not applicable to this problem, but may be handy another time): Tri-state or coloured check-boxes, allowing lines marked with different mark/colours to be saved in different files.

Comment: Suggestion: use the kill line feature of your preferred editor to remove the lines you don't want? `C-k` in `nano`, or `dd` in `vi`

Comment: @Panki Unfortunately, the number of lines I'll ignore greatly outnumber the lines I'll keep, so killing lines would be cumbersome.

Comment: If you can go without the checkbox, you can achieve it (including selecting to multiple different files) with Vim+mappings. If you raise that constraint, just ping me to add and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you can't work with your previous workflow,If comments were allowed for me( i just started using stack) I would say you can use the vim command `:v/*/d`
I don't get why it's more cumbersome. If you are forced to manually put stars(*) on every line of interest then the ticking of the hypothetical check-boxes might be even more troublesome.